# Why Progress Indicator is not starting from View Controller class?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a progress indicator in one of my classes, that is subclass of  NSViewController.It is connected with Outlet. When I'm trying to start indicator in initialization time of that class, and show content in main Window, from App Delegate, indicator is not starting what the reason?What I tried is here

```
[indicator startAnimiton:[self view]]; //in initWithNib function , but it's not starting
```

But when I try to start it from App Delegate

```
[MyClass.indicator startAnimation:self]; is working.
```

Did I miss something? How can I start Indicator from my Controller , when I initialize it.

Comment: If your question is about Cocoa on Mac OS X, use the ‘cocoa’ tag only. The ‘cocoa-touch’ tag is for questions about Cocoa Touch on iOS, e.g. iPhone or iPad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should start the progress indicator in [`awakeFromNib`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib) because only then all outlets are guaranteed to be connected.